# Marking position in a C# list

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of strings which have been read in from a dictionary file (sorted into alphabetical order). I want to create an index of the last position of each starting letter, so if there were 1000 words beginning with A it would be recorded as position 999 (because arrays start from 0). 1000 words beginning with B would mean the end position of B is 1999 and so on. These position values will be stored in a int array.

The only way I can think to do this is loop through the whole list, and have lots of else if statements to look at the first letter of the word. Not the most elegant solution.

Does anyone know of a simple way to do this, rather than 26 if statements?

Edit: The purpose of this is to generate random words. If I wanted a word beginning with B I would generate a random number between 1000 and 1999 and get the word from that position in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would handle this a different way, and it doesn't require it to be ordered.

```
    public List<string> GetAllStringsStartingWith(char startsWith, List<string> allWords)
    {
        List<string> letterSpecificWords = allWords.FindAll(word => word.ToLower()[0].Equals(startsWith));
        return letterSpecificWords;
    }
```

From here you now have a list containing only words that start with the letter "a".  You can change out "a" with a variable for whatever you need it to be, and it will always find all of them beginning with that letter.

Notes:

word.ToLower() is used to make sure it's a lowercase value.  If you switch the letter you're looking for to a variable, you'll want to do this on the variable as well.

You still need to handle the random integer, but you now have an accurate count (words.Count) to use.

This assumes no empty entries in the list.

words.ToLower()[0] gets the first character

Comment: That is a much better idea, I can just create a temporary list for each search. Thanks!

Comment: Do note that there's a slight performance decrease for doing it this way.  As long as you don't have 1 million+ entries, it won't make a difference.

Comment: why don't you just take the letter needed to randomize the word on as a parameter and put the char inside equals as a variable @Mike159

Comment: Please make sure your list names are correct.  It should not remove anything from the main list.  Also notice the update I just made.  This method should always return the sublist of words that starts with the "startsWith" character

Comment: The function explicitly stating that it is a char is helpful. I was using a string in the original code (derp).
Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Well, you could create a dictionary using LINQ:

```
// Note: assumes no empty words
Dictionary<char, int> lastEntries = words
    .Select((index, value) => new { index, value })
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.value[0])
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Max(p => p.index));
```

Or more usefully, keep the *first and last* indexes:

```
Dictionary<char, Tuple<int, int>> entryMinMax = words
    .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.value[0])
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                  g => Tuple.Of(g.Min(p => p.index), g.Max(p => p.index));
```

Alternatively, if the point is to effectively group the words by first letter, just do that, using a lookup:

```
ILookup<char, string> lookup = words.ToLookup(word => word[0]);
```

Then you can use:

```
char first = 'B'; // Or whatever
Random rng = new Random(); // But don't create a new one each time...
var range = lookup[first];
var count = range.Count();
if (count == 0)
{
    // No words starting with that letter!
}
int index = random.Next(count);
var randomWord = range.ElementAt(index);
```

Comment: The first section of code is giving this error:

Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'

Comment: @Mike159: Sorry, arguments are the wrong way round. Will fix.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case of an xy problem.  *Why* do you need the index of the last occurrence of each letter?  Chances are, this isn't really what you want to do.

To answer your question anyway, for each letter, you could use the [FindLastIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzs5503w(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
int index = myList.FindLastIndex(i => i.ToLower()[0] == 'a');
```

I like Jon Skeet's method better though since you don't have to loop through each letter.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the list with a for loop and compare the first letter of the current element to the first letter of the next element.  If the letter is the same continue the loop, if it is different then store the index of the next element and then continue the loop.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve last:

```
words.LastOrDefault(i => i[0].ToLower() == 'a');
```

To get index:

```
words.FindLastIndex(i => i[0].ToLower() == 'a');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this per one cycle:

```
public Dictionary<char, int> GetCharIndex(IList<string> words)
{
    if (words == null || !words.Any()) throw new ArgumentException("words can't be null or empty");
    Dictionary<char, int> charIndex = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    char prevLetter = words[0][0];
    for(int i = 1;i < words.Count;i++)
    {
        char letter = words[i][0];
        if (letter != prevLetter) //change of first letter of the word -> add previous letter to dictionary
        {
            charIndex.Add(prevLetter, i - 1);
            prevLetter = letter;
        }
    }
    charIndex.Add(words[words.Count - 1][0], words.Count - 1); //special case for last word
    return charIndex;
}
```